# Drupal 7 login loops back after site migration

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, drupal

Title says it all. Complete site migration. Everything else hooks up fine. Login goes nowhere. Googled everything I could think of to compare to this issue.

I did go from non-ssl to ssl. That works great. I am wondering if this might be an issue.

What I have done:

1. Cleared all cache tables on Production site (Does not work).
2. Deleted all cache tables on Production site (This actually lets me login. But after replacing the tables resets the issue).
3. Checked with host about mod_rewrite and everything is good there.

   Checked this cookie_domain thing and everything there looks in order.

Development site works just as it should.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following cases

1. Did you verify .htaccess and settings.php
2. Check $base_url and $cookie_domain in settings.php
3. Try clearing your browser cache.
4. Check if site is in maintenance mode
5. Verify database configurations

Comment: Done it. Going to try all again this week. Thanks for your answer. I will let you know.

Comment: Seems like it worked this time by changing the base_url. I had tried this a week or so ago and could not get it to work in any way. Thanks again!